What is the definition for circuit when it comes to computer networking?
I can't seem to find a definition for circuit when it comes to computer networking.
I'm always directed to "circuit switching" when I try to do some research. When I look at circuit switching, all I see are endpoints, ethernet cables, and switches.
So, what exactly are circuits?

Is this a question for homework?  I've never heard a network referred to as a circuit before.  The closest I can think of is that buildings that used old cable networks were referred to as token rings, but I don't think that is exactly what you're looking for.

Not for homework. I've just had conversations with people before and it seems like they would use circuit and router interchangeably.

a circuit is an individual physical link or the aggregate of the physical network links involved in a point to point connection. have you ever seen an old movie where a person picks up the telephone and the operator answers and asks who they want to call? then the operator plugs a wire from one port into another? this is an example of how the phone company used to create circuits. here is a picture of one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_switchboard#/media/File:Jersey_Telecom_switchboard_and_operator.jpg .

cont. modern telco networks are very different and don't involve people connecting wires to connect circuits; instead everything is always connected, and software and hardware are used to dynamically calculate and connect circuits between two end point. those circuits will potentially change over the course of a communication, based on the networks status (hence circuit switching), but its basically still the same thing.

The term "circuit switching" comes from telephone networking, where originally the "switches" would make a very long electrical connection between the caller and the recipient – a pair of wires was reserved for that particular call, for the duration of the call, and it literally formed a circuit in the electrical sense.
(Connections Museum on YouTube has a pair of videos on call tracing which show that each call was connected physically at every exchange.)
So while I don't think there's a strict definition, the main use of the term is to describe an established connection between two endpoints – a physical circuit would be a communications link dedicated to that purpose (e.g. a leased fiber), a virtual circuit would be something (such as a TCP connection) that imitates that kind of one-to-one communication without physically reserving anything.
There is no single physical device that would be called a 'circuit', however (by definition it is something made out of multiple devices), so you're not exactly going to see it. It definitely is not interchangeable with 'router', though – at best it would describe the connection between two routers. (Which could very well have been a leased phone line back in the day, or an Ethernet cable now, some other kind of connection that literally made an electric circuit.)
